# Querying through multiple tables in PHP SQL Joomla 3

Tags: php, sql, joomla3.2

My SQL skills are a little limited but I can figure out how to query things the long way.  Is there a better way to do this SQL statement below in one action instead of separating it into like three?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $query = "SELECT email FROM xx_opencart_customer WHERE customer_id = '".$this->session->data['customer_id']."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadObjectList();
                foreach ($results as $t) {;
                }

                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $query = "SELECT id FROM xx_users WHERE email = '".$t->email."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadObjectList();
                foreach ($results as $t) {;
                }

                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $query = "SELECT group_id FROM xx_user_usergroup_map WHERE user_id = '".$t->id."'";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadObjectList();
                foreach ($results as $t) {;
                }
```

The end result I am able to tell what $t->group_id equals to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT z.group_id 
          FROM #__opencart_customer x, #__users y, #__user_usergroup_map z 
          WHERE x.customer_id = ".
          $db->quote($this->session->data['customer_id']).
          " AND x.email = y.email AND y.id = z.user_id";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

For single value results, you don't need to use `$db->loadObjectList();`

For table names, don't use the actual dbprefix. Use `#_` instead. This way you can change table prefix from configuration.php without changing the queries.

Also, no need to set `$db = JFactory::getDbo();` everytime. Once is enough!

Hope this helps..
Cheers!

Comment: I added the $db->quote function which also escapes the input to prevent SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Tzar pls can this be done for multiple inserts too? I want to insert values into the Table1, retrieve the LAST_INSERT_ID(), and insert that and other values into Table2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Daydah I suppose you can do for multiple inserts as well. From your comment, I'm not quite clear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Tzar thanks for responding. What I want to accomplish is simple in normal SQL and I can illustrate using this Joomla quickfix [can this be done using the JFactory format in your solution?]: INSERT INTO `jx_users`
 (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`) 
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '');
INSERT INTO `jx_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
 VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');